# Formula to detect for doubles, and choose the one with the highest POP-number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have a problem with a formula that I can't seem to wrap my head around. When presented with the same Object, I need the formula to return a 1 when Object is there twice, at the row where the POP-number is the highest (Which would be POP03 every time). It does work, but the problem appears when Object is seen only once. It should give a 1 then as well, but I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Sample data looks as following;

```
+-------+------------+
|  POP  |   Object   |
+-------+------------+
| POP02 | B0005-8701 |
| POP02 | B0005-8702 |
| POP02 | B0005-8703 |
| POP02 | B0005-8704 |
| POP02 | B0006-4359 |
| POP02 | LBK-0013   |
| POP03 | LBK-0017   |
| POP02 | LBK-0017   |
| POP03 | LBK-0018   |
| POP02 | LBK-0018   |
| POP03 | LBK-0019   |
| POP02 | LBK-0019   |
| POP03 | LBK-0020   |
| POP02 | LBK-0020   |
| POP03 | LBK-0021   |
| POP02 | LBK-0021   |
+-------+------------+
```

Used formula is as following (POP is in Column B, and Object in Column C);

`=IF(C2="";"";IF(C2=C3;IF(Q2<Q3;0;IF(Q2>Q3;1;))))`

Comment: What is Q2Q3 in your formula?

Comment: What is the output you want?  Where do you want the 1 appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a countifs like this:

```
=IF(B$2:B$20="","",IF(COUNTIFS(C$2:C$20,C2,B$2:B$20,">"&B2)=0,1,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks for the quick answer.